# Pandoc Markdown to Plain Text Formatting

Tags: markdown, pandoc

There appears to be something amiss with the most recent installed version of Pandoc (pandoc 1.13.2.1) on my machines. With the previously installed version, conversion from markdown to plain text would generate `'Setext-style headers---'=' for H1 and '-' for H2---`in plain text output. In addition, I have noticed two more iffy issues:

- Pandoc now automatically generates uppercase letters for title
- Pandoc now precedes title with what seems to be two new lines (\n)

I have spent the last few minutes playing around with different pandoc options with little luck.

How do I convert **Illustration #1** to **Illustration #3**

Environment
    pandoc (pandoc 1.13.2.1)
    Kubuntu 15.10

Illustration #1: Input markdown file

```
# Title

## Section
* This is the section.

### Subsection
* This happens to be the subsection
```

Illustration #2: Output plain text after run `pandoc -f markdown -t plain pandoc_markdown_issue.md`

```
TITLE


Section

-   This is the section.

Subsection

-   This happens to be the subsection
```

Illustration #3: Desired Output

```
Title
=====

Section
-------
-   This is the section.

Subsection
----------
-   This happens to be the subsection
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The plain text writer was changed to use the general format of Project Gutenberg plain text books.  Of course, no choice will please everyone.  For the sample you give, using the markdown writer would work well.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I see, from the [changelog](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/6d91fb25639c6ac985d15c7112e009533d06e5f2/changelog), that this change was effected in 1.13

Answer (score 9):

I'm able to achieve your desired output by leaving out the `-f` and `-t` flags altogether and letting Pandoc infer the conversion format from the output filename extension:

```sh
pandoc file.md -o file.txt
```

Alternatively, using `-t plain` also seems to work:

```sh
pandoc -f markdown -t plain file.md -o file.txt
```

Not really sure why the first example works. My guess would be it's one of the markdown readers, since there are multiple.

Comment: This doesn't handle markdown links very well.

Answer (score 1):

> Pandoc now automatically generates uppercase letters for title

I had this issue with `-t plain` turning bold from docx into UPPER, worked around with a litte lua filter. First I did

```
$ pandoc -t native foo.docx
```

and saw that the text that was turned UPPER was surrounded in `Strong`, e.g. `[Para [Strong [Str "some text"]]]`. Non-bold text was like `[Para [Str "moar", Space, Str "text"]]`. So the filter becomes:

```lua
function Strong(element)
   return element.content
end
```

I put that in a file `weaken.lua` and then just

```
$ pandoc --lua-filter=weaken.lua -f docx -t plain foo.docx -o foo.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

It's weird but you can get close to the desired output by exporting to `rst` [reStructuredText](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/introduction.html) since it uses *setext-style* headings.
However you may face other issues, but it was just in case if it could be useful.

```sh
$ pandoc pandoc_markdown_issue.md -t rst
```

```
Title
=====

Section
-------

-  This is the section.

Subsection
~~~~~~~~~~

-  This happens to be the subsection
```

Comment: This doesn't handle markdown links very well.